# Visualizing sorting algorithm isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, visualization

I am trying to create a website which shows different sorting-algorithms by presenting the values of the array as bars and then sorting the array while updating the view.

I've got a method `drawArray()` which creats the bars and appends them to my `content`-div.
This method is called after every step of the sorting-algorithm, but it isn't showing the update on the website, instead, it just updates the view, when the sorting-algorithm is finished.

I assume there is an issue with updating the html from within a method or something, but I haven't figured out a way around this problem. Does anybody know how I could show the progress of the sorting?

This is my bubbleSort()-method:

```
var bubbleSort = function () {
    var n = array.length;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                var temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
            drawArray(null, null);
        }
        n = n - 1;
    } while (swapped)
}
```

with the `drawArray`-method call after each step.

Here is the `drawArray()`-method:
It could get two variables but this was only for testing, the method would highlight these two divs in a different color, but in the normal case, I just pass `null` so they appear black.

```
var drawArray = function (num1, num2) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(divs[i]);
        if (num1 == array[i]) {
            setDiv(divs[i], array[i], "red");
        } else {
            if (num2 == array[i]) {
                setDiv(divs[i], array[i], "blue");
            } else {
                setDiv(divs[i], array[i], "black");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `setDiv`-method which is called inside drawArray(), it basically just changes the height and color of the div:

```
var setDiv = function (div, height, farbe) {
   div.setAttribute('style', "color: white; font-family: Arial; height: " +
   height + "px; width: 10px; background-color: " + farbe + "; margin-left: 2px;
   margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;");
}
```

I am thankful for every help :)

EDIT: The problem seems to be that it is working too fast, so I need to delay each step of the sorting-algorithm. How can I do that?

Comment: Just use `setInterval()` to perform each swapping after a certain period of time.

Comment: Maybe it works too fast and you need a delay after each iteration.

Comment: @Manikiran I added it and now it just instantly shows the result, but still not the steps, but I think it's also working too fast.

Comment: @Roman yes, I'm pretty sure that's also a problem, which is why I tried using a way to delay every step, but I didn't find a solution on how to do it since `setTimeout` and others are just delaying the code inside, but the code afterwards is still getting executed. Do you know a good way to delay it?

Comment: Can you share your `drawArray` code? Is there anything inside that is asynchronous, why are the two values being passed `null`?

Comment: Can you include your approach to adding setTimeout? What values are you passing it?

Comment: @wlh Thanks for your answer, I edited the original post, so you can see the code :) The method just sets the div's size and color and appends them to my "content"-div

Comment: @Angrysheep I am not really experienced with JavaScript, so I tried to put a setTimeout around the `if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {` in my bubbleSort()-method, but then it would just exit the while-loop, because my `swapped` was set on false it was set on true too late.

Comment: @Nils OK, no problem. I'd put it around the `drawArray()` call, since you want to delay the draw, and not the execution of your algorithm. If you base the timeout on your loop counter, you should get something close to a consistent animation. You might also look into `requestAnimationFrame()`, if you need something more consistent.

Comment: @Angrysheep Thanks for your help :) But if I delay the `drawArray()`, the sorting is probably finished before anything is displayed, I would like to show it step by step, something similar to [this](https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Sorting-Visualizer/)

Comment: @Nils That's true, but the animation will still show step by step. Do you have a requirement that animation is in step with the algorithm? If so, you'll want to convert your code to async/await, Promise-based, or callback-based, in order to wait for each draw to complete, before proceeding.

Comment: @Angrysheep It isn't working with the step-by-step animation, if I put the drawArray() call in the setTimeout, because the array is a global variable, so drawArray always gets the most recent version. The sorting is finished, before the first drawArray() is executed.

Comment: @Nils I see. Sorry, I didn't notice that you had added `drawArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using setTimeount and operation counter. If you want to change array step by step. You can emulate for and while in interval;

```
var bubbleSort = function () {
    var n = array.length;
    var timeout = 1000;
    var swapped = false;
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (i >= n - 1) {
            n--;
            if (n === 1 || !swapped) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            }
            swapped = false;
            i = 0;
        }
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
        drawArray(null, null);
        i++;
    }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar solution, but it isn't working for me, because the setTimeout just delays the code inside (so the drawArray()) and not the execution of the sorting-algorithm, so the algorithm is finished before the first drawArray() is invoked.